# Web Scraping using Beautiful soup and saving it to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website in which the content is inside the div and various details inside various div class i am able to prettify the content using beautiful soup but i am not able to save it in dataframe as i dont want

here what i have tried

```
     unspsc_link = "https://www.besse.com/pages/products- 
     specialties/productsbyspecialty/urology/eligard"    
    link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
    
    div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'prdFormTable'})
    
    # Lists to store the scraped data in
    prdTitle      = []
    prdSubTitle   = []
    prdDesc       = []
    prdItemNumber = []
    prdNDC        = []
    prdCode       = []
    
    for links in div.find_all('div', {'class': 'prdFormTableRow'}):
        
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdTitle') is not None:
            name = links.text
            prdTitle.append(name)
            
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdSubTitle') is not None:
            sub = links.text
            prdSubTitle.append(sub)
            
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdDesc') is not None:
            sub = links.text
            prdDesc.append(sub)
    
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdItemNumber') is not None:
            sub = links.text
            prdItemNumber.append(sub)
            
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdNDC') is not None:
            sub = links.text
            prdNDC.append(sub)
    
        if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdCode') is not None:
            sub = links.text
            prdCode.append(sub)
    
    
    test_df = pd.DataFrame({'prdtitle': prdTitle,
    'subTitle': prdSubTitle,
    'prdDesc': prdDesc,
    'prdItemNumber': prdItemNumber,
    'prdNdc': prdNDC,
    'prdcode': prdCode
    })
```

It does save vale in the list but not in correct format

```
   when i print(prdTitle)  

        ['\n\n\n\n\nELIGARD® 7.5mg Kit (1 Month) \nTolmar Pharmaceuticals\nLeuprolide acetate for injectable suppression, 7.5mg every month. ELIGARD is the only LHRH agonist with the innovative ATRIGEL® Delivery System. \n\n\nItem # 44768 \nNDC: 62935-0753-75\nHCPCS CODE: J9217 \n\n\n\n\xa090 Day Terms\r\n           \n            \r\n           Credit Card   Next Day Delivery\r\n         \r\n         \n\nPLACE ORDER\n\n',
         '\n\n\n\n\n\u200bELIGARD® 22.5mg Kit (3 Month)  \nTolmar Pharmaceuticals\nLeuprolide acetate for injectable suppression, 22.5mg every 3 months. ELIGARD is the only LHRH agonist with the innovative ATRIGEL® Delivery System. \n\n\nItem # 44769 \nNDC: 62935-0223-05\nHCPCS CODE: J9217 \n\n\n\n\xa090 Day Terms\r\n           \n            \r\n           Credit Card   Next Day Delivery\r\n         \r\n         \n\nPLACE ORDER\n\n',
         '\n\n\n\n\nELIGARD® 30mg Kit (4 Month) \nTolmar Pharmaceuticals\nLeuprolide acetate for injectable suppression, 30mg every 4 months. ELIGARD is the only LHRH agonist with the innovative ATRIGEL® Delivery System. \n\n\nItem # 44770 \nNDC:  \u200b62935-0303-30\nHCPCS CODE: J9217 \n\n\n\n\xa090 Day Terms\r\n           \n            \r\n           Credit Card   Next Day Delivery\r\n         \r\n         \n\nPLACE ORDER\n\n',
         '\n\n\n\n\nELIGARD® 45mg Kit (6 Month) \nTolmar Pharmaceuticals\nLeuprolide acetate for injectable suppression, 45mg every 6 months. ELIGARD is the only LHRH agonist with the innovative ATRIGEL® Delivery System. \n\n\nItem # 44771 \nNDC: \u200b62935-0453-45\nHCPCS CODE: J9217 \n\n\n\n\xa090 Day Terms\r\n           \n            \r\n           Credit Card   Next Day Delivery\r\n         \r\n         \n\nPLACE ORDER\n\n']
```

In prdTitle list it contain all the the details but i want to store only the prdTitle followed by other list with desired values

Comment: What do  you mean by " not in correct format"/

Comment: please show the desired output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to work with what you have found at the level below:

```
if links.find('div', class_ = 'prdTitle') is not None:
    name = links.text
    prdTitle.append(name)
```

The above is still working with `links` rather than the result of `links.find`.

Using `select_one` you could do the following (same as `find`) i.e. set result into a variable and work with that.

Consider also that using a dictionary will more efficient that always appending to lists.

```
prdTitles = []
prdSubTitles = []
prdDescs = []
prdItemNumbers = []
prdNDCs = []
prdCodes = []

for row in soup.select('.prdFormTableRow'):
    prdTitle = row.select_one('.prdTitle')
    if prdTitle is None:
        prdTitles.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdTitles.append(prdTitle.text.strip().replace('\u200b',''))

    prdSubTitle = row.select_one('.prdSubTitle')
    if prdSubTitle is None:
        prdSubTitles.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdSubTitles.append(prdSubTitle.text.strip())

    prdDesc = row.select_one('.prdDesc')
    if prdDesc is None:
        prdDescs.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdDescs.append(prdDesc.text.strip())    

    prdItemNumber = row.select_one('.prdItemNumber')
    if prdItemNumber is None:
        prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdItemNumbers.append(prdItemNumber.text.strip())

    prdNDC = row.select_one('.prdNDC')
    if prdNDC is None:
        prdNDCs.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdNDCs.append(prdNDC.text.strip())

    prdCode = row.select_one('.prdCode')
    if prdCode is None:
        prdCodes.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdCodes.append(prdCode.text.strip())
```

Comment: how would i save all the list into single dataframe @QHarr